# Youtube iframe embed won't work if channel has spaces in the name

Tags: video, iframe, youtube, embed, youtube-channels

I've been trying to get a channel's uploads onto a site through HTML and the use of iframe works perfectly for what I need. 
The only problem is as soon as you put in the channel name with spaces it shows a playback error. Of course it's a completely different channel if I remove the spaces. I tried using nbsp but no luck there. 
If it's too much trouble I'll just tell the person their youtube name needs to change but ideally I'd love to see if there's a workaround. 

Here's the code for reference:

```html
<iframe src="http://www.youtube.com/embed?listType=user_uploads&list=CHANNELNAME" width="480" height="400" frameBorder="0"></iframe>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to HTML encode the spaces as %20 (nbsp is a different character altogether so won't work).